# jquery each loop with index other than zero

Tags: jquery

I have array. I have to run loop after indexing 1. I google it but did not find any answer so I did it by use of `for` `loop`. Is there any way to get this done by using of jquery without any extra effort . Like using slice and all that.

```
var myAr= ['a','b','c','d']
for(i=2;i<myAr.length;i++){
alert(myAr[i])
}


$.each(myAr,function(){
// what goes here
})
```

Comment: Both answers below are correct — see [$.each documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(myAr,function(index){
    if(index < 2) {
        return;
    }
    // your code
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (index < 2)`?

Comment: Yes it should.Thanks.

Comment: But I see no difference from the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the array first:

```
$.each(myAr.slice(2), function(i, val) {
    ...
});
```

Inside the function, the indexes will be 2 less than they would be if you were processing the original array.

Performance-wise, the `for` loop is probably best. It only processes the desired elements of the array, and it doesn't perform any function calls.

Next are the answers that test the index within the loop.

My solution is probably worst, because it has to make 2 passes through the array: once to make the slice, and then to perform the `$.each` loop over the slice. It also uses more memory, because the slice is a new array.

Comment: Ok as I mention in my question. Is there any way without using slice. But I think performance wise this answer is better

Comment: Actually, this is probably the worst performance. I added an explanation of why.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

I am pretty sure that pure javascript is faster than the JQuery one, but it is a convenient function :

```
$.each(myAr,function(index, value){
    if(index > 1) {
        alert(key + ": " + value)
    }    
})
```

Comment: But loop is running through out the array. I want to avoid that.

Comment: @amit Then use the `for` loop, what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "div" ).each( function( i ){
  if( i == 0 ) return; 
  console.log( this );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> </div>
<div> </div>
```

Comment: Should be `if (i < 2)`